# Do the sequences with divergent associated $\zeta$-function form a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis

Let $V$ be the set of sequences $a \in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$. The set $V$ can be seen as a real vector space, with pointwise addition and scalar multiplication.

For $a\in V$ we define the "associated $\zeta$-function" to be \begin{eqnarray} \zeta(a) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1+|a_n|}}
\end{eqnarray}
(similar to post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187610/almost-zeta-function)

Let $D = \{a\in V: \zeta(a) = \infty\}$. Is $D\subseteq V$ a subspace?

Comment: What do you want to do about $D$ not containing $\vec 0$?

Comment: $D$ does contain the constant 0 sequence because the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: Oops, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define 
$$
a_n=\begin{cases}\frac{2\log\log n}{\log n}&:&\text{$n$ is odd,}\\0&:&\text{$n$ is even,}\end{cases}\hspace{1cm}b_n=\begin{cases}0&:&\text{$n$ is odd,}\\\frac{2\log\log n}{\log n}&:&\text{$n$ is even.}\end{cases}
$$
It's not hard to check that $\zeta(a)=\zeta(b)=\infty$, but $\zeta(a+b)<\infty$, so $D$ is not closed under addition.